# How to implement variables into function names

Tags: python

I'm making a sudoku board using turtle in python. Right now I'm having a little trouble trying to figure out how to let the program easily check which box I am looking at. I have 5 grids in different positions. The game will automatically pick one to play. Since each grid is in a different position, I have to be careful where I have my turtle positioned. I have 16 functions that calculate where I want my turtle cursor to be to draw the number.

```
#Below is a guide to where each box is relative to its position on the grid. 

#To find center of the box, add 75 to x and 20 to y.
#Box(1,1) = x, y        Box(1,2) = x+150, y        Box(1,3) = x+300, y        Box(1,4) = x+450, y
#Box(2,1) = x, y-150    Box(2,2) = x+150, y-150    Box(2,3) = x+300, y-150    Box(2,4) = x+450, y-150
#Box(3,1) = x, y-300    Box(3,2) = x+150, y-300    Box(3,3) = x+300, y-300    Box(3,4) = x+450, y-300
#Box(4,1) = x, y-450    Box(4,2) = x+150, y-450    Box(4,3) = x+300, y-450    Box(4,4) = x+450, y-450

def box1_1(x, y):
    return(x+75, y+20)

def box1_2(x, y):
    return(x+225, y+20)

def box1_3(x, y):
    return(x+375, y+20)

def box1_4(x, y):
    return(x+525, y+20)

def box2_1(x, y):
    return(x+75, y-130)

def box2_2(x, y):
    return(x+225, y-130)

def box2_3(x, y):
    return(x+375, y-130)

def box2_4(x, y):
    return(x+525, y-130)

def box3_1(x, y):
    return(x+75, y-280)

def box3_2(x, y):
    return(x+225, y-280)

def box3_3(x, y):
    return(x+375, y-280)

def box3_4(x, y):
    return(x+525, y-280)

def box4_1(x, y):
    return(x+75, y-430)

def box4_2(x, y):
    return(x+225, y-430)

def box4_3(x, y):
    return(x+375, y-430)

def box4_4(x, y):
    return((x+525, y-430))
```

I can get the boards to be drawn how I want and the given numbers are also drawn correctly. I want the user to have the option to play with real time correction or play traditionally where they can enter all the values and the game will check if their solution is correct. The problem I am running into is during the part where the user enters in their desired number into a box. Right now I have:

```
def playSudoku():
    playboard = []
    board1 = [[0,0,0,3],[0,1,0,4],[4,2,0,1],[0,3,4,0]]
    board2 = [[4,3,0,0],[1,0,3,0],[0,0,2,0],[2,1,0,0]]
    board3 = [[0,4,0,1],[3,0,3,0],[1,0,0,4],[0,2,1,0]]
    board4 = [[1,0,3,0],[0,4,2,1],[0,0,0,2],[0,0,4,0]]
    board5 = [[0,4,3,2],[3,0,0,0],[4,0,0,0],[0,0,4,1]]
    boardchoice = random.randint(1,5)
    if boardchoice == 1:
        drawBoard1()
        playboard = board1
        posx = -900
        posy = 850
    elif boardchoice == 2:
        drawBoard2()
        playboard = board2
        posx = -200
        posy = 850
    elif boardchoice == 3:
        drawBoard3()
        playboard = board3
        posx = 500
        posy = 850
    elif boardchoice == 4:
        drawBoard4()
        playboard = board4
        posx = -500
        posy = 100
    else:
        drawBoard5()
        playboard = board5
        posx = 200
        posy = 100
    rtc = turtle.textinput("Sudoku", "Do you want to play with real time correction?")
    if rtc == 'y':
        for i in range (0,3):
            for j in range (0,3):
                if playboard[i][j] != 0:
                    pass
                num = turtle.numinput('Sudoku', 'Enter a number for box[' + str(i) + ',' + str(j) + ']?: ', minval=1, maxval=4)
                turtle.goto(box[i]_[j](posx,posy))
                turtle.write(str(num), move=True, align="center", font=("Times New Roman", 24))
```

I want to bring attention specifically to this line

```
turtle.goto(box[i]_[j](posx,posy))
```

The reason why each board has a different posx and posy is because they sit in different spots on the turtle grid. So as you saw above, I have functions with names "box**A** _ **B**" where A and B are the position numbers for the box. I know that what I wrote doesn't work (I tried it too, just in case), but I was wondering if there was a python function out there that would let me do what I'm trying to achieve. 
In my loop, whatever i and j are, I would like my my program to use box[i]_[j].
I apologize if this is poorly worded. If more clarification is needed, I will eagerly tell you. I was just hoping someone out there knows what I'm looking for.

Comment: The advice in the following blog post [**_Keep data out of your variable names_**](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) is relevant.

Comment: What martineau said. If ever you find yourself creating a whole series of numbered variables like your board1..board5 that's a sign that you're doing something wrong, and those boards should be items in a list, or perhaps a dict.

Comment: Similarly, «functions with names "boxA _ B"» can probably done much more efficiently. Ideally, all those functions could be combined into a single function. But if they can't, there are ways that you can create a 2D grid of functions, which you could call like `boxfunc[a][b](posx, poy)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably define the `box` function like this.

```
def box(i, j, x, y):
    return (x + 150*j - 75, y - 150*i + 170)
```

Then just call `box(i, j, posx, posy)` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the equation I was looking for. I feel super silly seeing it in front of me now. Cheers!

Comment: In case you wanted an update, I implemented that and it works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Although in this particular case writing a generic `box()` function as shown in the other answer would be the best approach since the function's result can be determined via a relatively simply formula from the `i` and `j` arguments. However in more general circumstances where that's not true, you'd want to use something like a dictionary to map the different possible combinations to the desired function. Below is how that could have been to solve your problem.

First add a dictionary to associate the different argument values with the corresponding function:

```
box_map = {
    (1, 1): box1_1,
    (1, 2): box1_2,
    (1, 3): box1_3,
    (1, 4): box1_4,
    (2, 1): box2_1,
    (2, 2): box2_2,
    (2, 3): box2_3,
    (2, 4): box2_4,
    (3, 1): box3_1,
    (3, 2): box3_2,
    (3, 3): box3_3,
    (3, 4): box3_4,
    (4, 1): box4_1,
    (4, 2): box4_2,
    (4, 3): box4_3,
    (4, 4): box4_4,
}
```

Next would be to modify the `playSudoku()` function to use it to lookup the function to call:

```
      ...
    rtc = turtle.textinput("Sudoku", "Do you want to play with real time correction?")
    if rtc == 'y':
        for i in range (0,3):
            for j in range (0,3):
                if playboard[i][j] != 0:
                    pass
                num = turtle.numinput('Sudoku', 'Enter a number for box[' + str(i) + ',' + str(j) + ']?: ', minval=1, maxval=4)
#                turtle.goto(box[i]_[j](posx, posy))
                turtle.goto(box_map[i, j](posx, posy))
                turtle.write(str(num), move=True, align="center", font=("Times New Roman", 24))
```